# Задать авторазмер UserControl передаваемого в TabPage

Tags: c#, winforms, usercontrol, tabcontrol

Есть отдельный `UserControl`, который я передаю в `TabPage` и юзаю его в `TabControl`

```
private static UserControl_Connection _Connection = new UserControl_Connection();

TabPage tp = new TabPage();
tp.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
tp.Controls.Add(_Connection);
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);
```

Каким образом я могу задать свойство `Dock=Fill` для юзерконтролла `_Connection` так, чтобы открывая его во вкладке он заполнял свободное пространство `TabControl`? Возможно, это задается не через `Dock=Fill`, какое решение?

Comment: у вас же после добавления контрола в TabPage остается прямая ссылка на него в переменной _Connection. Что мешает с ее помощью задать значение свойства Dock? `_Connection.Dock=DockStyle.Fill`

Comment: @rdorn И смешно и страшно, что я до этого не додумался. Спасибо. Оформите, как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static UserControl_Connection _Connection = new UserControl_Connection();

TabPage tp = new TabPage();
tp.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
tp.Controls.Add(_Connection);
//-----------
_Connection.Dock=DockStyle.Fill;
//-----------
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);
```